# How to loop through multiple pages in multiple urls Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of urls and I want my code to loop through multiple pages of these multiple urls

```
urls = ['https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2019-adding-adaptive-cruise-454662/','https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise-control-sensor-blockage-446041/']

comments = []

for url in urls:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for item in range(1):
            response = req.get(url+"index{item}/")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
            for item in soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"ism-true"}):
                result = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
                comments.append(result)
```

The above code through an error. Can you let me know how to loop through multiple pages. The error I am getting is "NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll"

Comment: Try https://scrapy.org/

Comment: _The above code through an error_ It would help a lot if you showed us the error.

Comment: I think `r.content` should be `response.content`

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @anonymous13 : how many records are you expecting per page.I am getting 10 records per page for first url and 7 records per page for second url.

Answer (score 1):

`soup` can return `None`.
Only continue if soup has a value.

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    if soup:  
        for item in soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"ism-true"}):
            result = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
            comments.append(result)
```

Note that `response.content` is the response in binary, 
`response.text` is it in string form. If matching fails at all time, try the string form.

It also looks like you want an f-string for the url, if "item" is a number:

```
 for item in range(1):
        response = req.get(f"{url}index{item}/")
```

Comment: Thank you so much  f"{url}index{item}/" this worked for me.